# Finding the probability of being dealt exactly one pair of cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to find the probability of being dealt exactly one pair of the same denomination in a 5 card hand. Do I need to divide by ${52 \choose 5}$ to find the probability?

There are $\binom{13}{1}$ ways to pick denomination, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to pick a pair, $\binom{12}{3}$ ways to pick other 3 cards and $\binom{4}{1}^3$ ways to pick suit of 3 cards.

$${13 \choose 1} {4 \choose 2} {12 \choose 3} {4 \choose 1}^{3}$$

Comment: That's how I would do it...

Comment: ... and yes, you do divide that by $\tbinom{52}5$.

Comment: I will point out that all of these numbers involved in your question depend heavily on what type of deck you are using.  The numbers used for example would be very different in a euchre deck than in a standard poker deck.  For completeness, you should include in the problem statement that we are using a [standard 52card deck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck).

Comment: For your proposed solution, endorsed in two Comments, the numerical answer is 0.422569. A simulation of a million hands gave $0.423 \pm 0.001.$